FLS CRUD checks in apex
I current have 200 medium issues flagged in checkmarx as my code scanner.
Can I ask if this is an actual security issue? My understanding is even if I don't do the crud check, the user running the code will still need permissions to the fields in question for it to work. So why do we need to do it?
Thanks!

Yes, it is an actual security issue.
Apex runs in "system mode" by default, no matter which user is the running user, which means that FLS is not being checked. I don't believe there is currently any way for us to change out of system mode (even Test.runAs() doesn't apply FLS) at the transaction level.
Even if your classes all specify with sharing, FLS is still not being checked (sharing determines which records are visible to users. It's a row-level check and not a field-level check).
The only ways I know of that we have to currently enforce FLS are:

Manually checking DescribeFieldResult properties (i.e. the old and painful way)
Using WITH USER_MODE (preferred) or WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED (older, missing some benefits) in SOQL queries
Using Security.stripInaccessible()
Using as user when performing DML (e.g.insert as user someNewAccounts;)


As a sub bullet to #1, a lightweight helper library comes in handy for reducing the pain of the manual checks. One such library is in the security section of the apex recipes repository, CanTheUser. Documentation found here: CanTheUser documentation

also fflib apex-common includes USER MODE and SYSTEM MODE if using that framework (sub-bullet 2)
